# Tinkerpop Gremlin Get Edges that go to vertices within a list

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm trying to query for edges that go to vertices within an aggregated list. It sounds quite simple, and it should be, but I seem to be writing my queries wrong, and I just can't figure out why. Anyway, I'll use the Modern Toy Graph to make an example, that won't necessarily make much sense in this context, but still illustrates what I wish to do:

```
graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
g = graph.traversal()

g.V().
  hasLabel('person').
    aggregate('x').
  outE().
    where(inV().is(within('x')))
```

What I'm doing is traversing to all 'person' vertices, aggregating them, then trying to get all the outgoing edges that lead to another vertex within that aggregated list. I expect the above query to return [the edge labelled "knows" that goes between vertex 1 and 2, and the one between 1 and 4](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.6/images/tinkerpop-modern.png), however nothing is returned. If i simple want to get the vertices on the other end of those edges, rather than the edges themselves, the following works fine, returning vertex 2 and 4:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('person').
    aggregate('x').
  out().
    where(within('x'))
```

So how can I get edges that lead to vertices already aggregated in a list?

(Once again, I'm aware this example doesn't make much sense within this particular graph, and I could easily query outE('knows'), but this query is relevant to a different graph.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `is()` quite that way. An easy fix would be to just combine your "working" traversal with the one that doesn't:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   aggregate('x').
......2>   outE().
......3>   where(inV().where(within('x')))
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I tried both `where(inV().within('x'))` and `where(inV().is().within('x'))` which both gave errors and assumed the above may be the correct usage of `is()`, being that it, at least, didn't error out. I never considered adding another `where()` step. Thanks again.